# How to bootstrap application with Webpack

Tags: webpack, marionette

I'm working on switch my Marionette app from requirejs to Webpack and after a LOT of issues, I'm almost there, but there's one thing I just can't figure out: how to bootstrap my app.

With requirejs I just reclared a global variable `var app;` in which I store my main Marionette.Application object so I can access it from my other files.

However, Webpack changes `this` from `window` to the current module, so my `var app;` is suddendly not global anymore.

I tried assigning them all to `window`: `window.app;` but I still can't access them from other modules.

My last try was using `ProvidePlugin` but I get empty object in all the files except the first one, so I removed it.

My current code is:

bootstrap.js (main entry point in `webpack.config.js`):
    import App from "apps/main";

```
// Start history when our window.app.ication is ready
app.listenTo(app, 'start', function() {
    var that = this;
    $.when(
        this.auth.checkAuth()
    ).always(function(){
        that.router.start();
    });
});

app.start();
```

apps/main.js:

```
import Router from "routers/mainRouter";

module.exports = new Marionette.Application({ 
    initialize: function(){
      this.router = new Router();
    }   
});
```

router/mainRouter.js:

```
import App from "apps/main";

module.exports = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    start: function(){    
        App.something();
    },
});
```

in `mainRouter` I get: can't do something() on undefined.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You have circular dependencies - `apps/main.js` imports `router/mainRouter.js`, but `router/mainRouter.js` also imports `apps/main.js`. Webpack has to make a choice of which one to resolve first, so App is undefined while your router code is executing.

You'll need to restructure your code so that the circular dependency is no longer present - the simplest solution would be to move your router code into `apps/main.js`. That said, I don't work with Marionette personally, so there may be more elegant ways to fix this that I don't know about.

Comment: I thought the whole point of Webpack was that since it compiles code, it can be smart with circular dependencies. If not it removes a lot of his usefulness.

Anyhow, that's why I asked about global variables, if I can make my "app" object global, then I do not need to import it in the router since I can already access it. But looks like there's no way to simulate a simple global variable.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can isolate your imports momentarily and then walk through the file webpack builds.  You should be able to do this. One thing I'm not 100% sure about looking at this code.  You're using ES6 imports and commonjs module exports.  I think you want `export default new Marionette.Application({ ... });`